# Global accessor State Machine Handler move_and_slide problem

Tags: godot

im currently having a problem with a statemachine that i am coding, the problem that is occurring is that when i add move_and_slide to the state of movement, the if condition at the last of the code block is getting the error:

the method " move_and_slide isn't declared in the current class

```rust
    extends Node2D

    class_name State

    var state_machine = null
    var player_velocity = Vector2()
    var player_speed = 200

    enum playerStates{IDLE, WALK, RUN, USE, SHOOT}
    enum ItemStates{ITEM_ON_GROUND, IS_EQUIPED}

   func _ready():
        if Global.player_isIdle == State.state_machine == playerStates.IDLE:
            pass
        if Global.player_isWalking == State.state_machine == playerStates.WALK:
            player_velocity = Global.player_velocity
    func handle_input(_event: InputEvent):
        if player_velocity != player_velocity.ZERO:
            if Global.player_isWalking == State.state_machine == playerStates.WALK:
                pass
            if Global.player_isRunning == State.state_machine == playerStates.RUN:
               if Input.is_action_pressed("sprint"):
                    player_speed = 300
            Global.player_velocity = Global.player_velocity.normalized() * player_speed
            Global.player_velocity = move_and_slide(Global.player_velocity)
    func _physics_process(_delta):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called `move_and_slide` but it belongs to `KinematicBody2D` (or its 3D counterpart).

However, you are writing code in a `Node2D`. As the error message tell you, there isn't a `move_and_slide` for `Node2D`.

Since there isn't a `move_and_slide` in `Node2D`, you could write your own method called `move_and_slide` that does whatever you want. However, I believe you want to use the one form `KinematicBody2D`.

So change the `Node` from `Node2D` to `KinematicBody2D` (and update the script, at the top, where it says `extends Node2D` to say `KinematicBody2D`). In the Godot editor you can find an option to change the type of a `Node` called "Change Type", it is in the contextual menu of the `Node` in Scene.

Comment: i was thinking something like this
https://www.gdquest.com/tutorial/godot/design-patterns/finite-state-machine/

Comment: @PH4z Are you having trouble with something from that tutorial? - I'm going to assume that want another `Node` to manipulate the `KinematicBody2D`. How to do that will depend on how they are related in the scene tree or otherwise (if it is the parent, as Rohit is guessing, then their answer is viable, so it might serve as starting point). Btw, notice most of your code is in `_ready`, I don't think that is intentional. Yet, I'm not sure how do you want it to work. My suggestion is to follow the tutorial more closely, and post question about the parts of the tutorial that are giving you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

```
extends Node2D
class_name State
```

your class is extending Node2D but `move_and_slide` is from `KinematicBody2D`
Try:

```
extends KinematicBody2D
class_name State
```

and also use `move_and_slide` in `_physics_update` function.
Also, don't forget to change Player Node to **KinematicBody2D**

*and if your Class is a child of **Player** node then do like this:*

```
extends Node2D

class_name State

    var state_machine = null
    var player_velocity = Vector2()
    var player_speed = 200

    var parent = get_parent() <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 

    enum playerStates{IDLE, WALK, RUN, USE, SHOOT}
    enum ItemStates{ITEM_ON_GROUND, IS_EQUIPED}

   func _ready():
        if Global.player_isIdle == State.state_machine == playerStates.IDLE:
            pass
        if Global.player_isWalking == State.state_machine == playerStates.WALK:
            player_velocity = Global.player_velocity
    
func handle_input(_event: InputEvent):
        if player_velocity != player_velocity.ZERO:
            if Global.player_isWalking == State.state_machine == playerStates.WALK:
                pass
            if Global.player_isRunning == State.state_machine == playerStates.RUN:
               if Input.is_action_pressed("sprint"):
                    player_speed = 300
            Global.player_velocity = Global.player_velocity.normalized() * player_speed
            
    
func _physics_process(_delta):
    Global.player_velocity = parent.move_and_slide(Global.player_velocity) <<<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: what is your email, id like to add you as a team member please

Comment: its nexero0044@gmail.com